# How to append and replace text in URL with jQuery without reloading?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have done pagination in wordpress with Jquery/Ajax/wp_pagenavi() which instead of reloading page refreshes only a div to load new content, it works fine but I would like to update part of URL as well - without reloading the page.With jQuery pagination url for Page 1, Page 2, Page 3  doesn't change and is always same : myhost.com/category/

I want it look as it would look with standard pagination :

add '/page/$paginated_page_number/' to base URL which is myhost.com/download/category/

```
myhost.com/download/category/page/2/
myhost.com/download/category/page/3/
myhost.com/download/category/page/4/  ... ...
```

I also plan to use jQuery div refresh for tags and I need to change part of URL without reloading page, when tag is choosen I will refresh div with new content and update URL :

replace : '/download/category/' to '/tag/$choosen_tag/'

How to replace part of URL without reloading the page ?

Comment: Do you have any HTML to go with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like HTML5 [pushState](http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate). This new API allows the developer to change the URL displayed in browser via JavaScript without reloading the page.

I must warn though you that this is not yet supported by IE. IE team has plans to support it in verison 10.

More about [browser history manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Hope it helps.